# Settings disappeared in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.10

I usually go to the right top corner and at the drop down menu I select the tool icon to go to the settings.

However, 19.10 does not have a tool icon.

How can I go to settings now?

Comment: the button should be present. i see it with my 19.10. Anyway, open a terminal and type `gnome-control-center`or ALT+F2 then type it

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of the following command in Terminal: `apt policy gnome-control-center`

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for your hints.

This helped:

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

Strange, that it wasn't installed during upgrade?

Comment: Thanks! The same thing happened on 20.04 LTS, and this fixed it. Weird.

Comment: Also worked for Ubuntu 22.04